# Key schortcut in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, dom-events, keyboard-shortcuts

I am trying to make a simple shortcut feature for my site and I am very new in JavaScript. Basically simple thing: when somebody presses <kbd>n</kbd>-key (keycode:78) jump to page "display.php", and I want this to work on all platforms (IE, Mozilla etc.).

Answer (score 0):

To ensure cross-browser functionality it is a good idea to rely on common libraries like jQuery. There's a method to do this: http://api.jquery.com/keypress/

Try this

```
$('body').keypress(function(event) {
  if (event.which == '78') {
     window.location.href = 'yourURL';
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.onkeyup = KeyCheck;       

    function KeyCheck(e)
    {
       var KeyID = (window.event) ? event.keyCode : e.keyCode;
       switch(KeyID)
       {
          case KEY_CODE:
          document.Form1.KeyName.value = "...";
          <!-- DO STUFF --> 
       }
    }
 </script>
```